# How to write SQL for inner join of three tables selection

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables:

**Item

ItemCategories

Categories**

If ItemCategories contain:
**id

itemID

categoryID**

How would I write the SQL to get the category name of the item?

So far I have:

```
Select * 
from
   items, 
   itemCategories, 
   categories
where 
  item.id = itemCategories.itemID
  and categories.id = itemCategories.categoryID
```

Comment: so whats the problem with your query now?

Comment: @JohnWoo - I made a typo! I had item.id instead of items.id but I was still missing the other parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the JOIN form of your comma separated table join.

```
select *
  from items i
  join itemCategories ic on i.id = ic.itemID
  join categories c on c.id = ic.categoryID
```

It is normally also a very good idea to

1. use short alias names for the tables
2. list ALL and ONLY the fields you need in the SELECT clause

   - as shown, the id column exists in both `items` and `categories` which makes it ambiguous to refer to in front-end apps consuming the result of this query

To get a specific category name given an item name

```
select c.name
  from items i
  join itemCategories ic on i.id = ic.itemID
  join categories c on c.id = ic.categoryID
 where i.name = 'itemname'
```

Note: this can return multiple category names if an item can be in multiple categories.

Comment: +1. Beat me to it by about 10 keystrokes and a mouse click. :-)

Comment: does the old syntax (*on the example above*) performs `outer join`?

Comment: It performs an INNER JOIN, but it's not JOIN-syntax

Comment: Fast response! :) I think this will do it.